# 5-Chloro-2-Methylphenol vs 2-Chloro-5-Methylbenzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Why is the compound called 5-Chloro-2-Methylphenol rather than 2-Chloro-5-methylphenol? The occurence of the highest number 5 is exactly the same, so are they both correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two compound names that you are asking about refer to different compounds. Phenol is numbered as follows:

[image: An image showing the numbering of cabron atoms in phenol, with the carbon bearing the hydroxy group numbered 1 and the remaining numbers 2 through 6 assigned clockwise around the ring]

The structures of 2-chloro-5-methylphenol and 5-chloro-2-methyl phenol are below.

[image: The structures of 2-chloro-5-methylphenol and 5-chloro-2-methylphenol emphasizing the numbering of the carbon atoms]

Perhaps you were confused about the 2,6 or 3,5 isomers? In this case, the chloro- substituent should get the lower locant number because it is alphabetically first.

[image: The structures of 2-chloro-6-methylphenol and 3-chloro-5-methylphenol emphasizing the numbering of the carbon atoms]